# Необходимый уровень знаний для изучения фреймворков

Tags: javascript, framework

Каким уровнем знаний языка javascript должен обладать программист для того чтобы можно было изучать фреймворки к нему (вроде jquery) и полноценно ими пользоваться?

Comment: Вопрос на который нет и не может быть правильного ответа.
Каким уровнем знаний английского должен обладать человек, чтобы можно было полноценно разговаривать с англичанами? Кому-то достаточно жестов, а кто-то считает что оксфордского сертификата мало.

Comment: Для справки, jQuery -- не фреймворк, а библиотека.

Comment: все зависит от Вашего окружения. Если Вас окружают опытные программисты, то Вы вместе с расспросами "как сделать" будите ещё спрашивать "а почему именно так". А вот если такого окружения нет, то как минимум один седой волос Вам гарантирован.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно узкий вопрос.
Точных рамок нет, но абсолютно точно только тогда, когда научишься на голом языке решать **все** те задачи, которые хочешь возложить на фреймворк.

---

Сейчас куча JS-"программистов", которые искренне уверены что `jQuery` - это и есть язык. А всё из-за желания побыстрее начать клепать и получать на конфетки.
`jQuery` (это вроде библиотека, а не фрейморк, нет?) помогает лишь тем, кто уже знает `JS` и может сделать эту задачу без `jQuery`, остальных берёт в плагинрабство. Как и любой подобный продукт.

---

Изучать как **пользоваться** ими - это одно, изучать как **устроен** - совсем другое.
Изучать внутреннюю кухню на порядок сложнее, но интересно и точно поднимает уровень профессионализма. Сорцы таких штук легко найти на `GitHub`.

Answer (score 0):

Знать сам язык и навыки программирования. После можно изучить фреймворк и пользоваться им.